# Bigquery: why set job id not work?

Tags: google-bigquery

when we work with query/load jobs, we meet SocketReadTimeOut sometimes, as recommended [in this book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=LDaiAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=bigquery%20generate%20job%20id&source=bl&ots=dDLrXQStnq&sig=qp_iaCp9DQnKSqD3YO_XJH2P9_w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gvsaVOGzL4mPyASI5IG4AQ&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=bigquery%20generate%20job%20id&f=false)
we want to set job id by ourselves so that we can check job status in this case and ensure no duplicated job are submitted to invalidate our data. But it does not work as everytime a new job id will be generated by Bigquery. For example, as shown below:

```
... 
job.setConfiguration(config);
job.setId("job_wRGTy7WaCKKcTdlE-nDWGDTZVI4");
Bigquery.Jobs.Insert insert = sBIGQUERY.jobs().insert(mProjectId, job,content);
JobReference jobRef = insert.execute().getJobReference();
System.out.println(jobRef.getJobId());
```

the print out from last line is not "job_wRGTy7WaCKKcTdlE-nDWGDTZVI4" but "job_CnuEOr4IEKHjLls-U1UDSBS0K-4". Why? And how can I set job id correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "id" is an output only field that is an artifact of the REST api requirements ('all objects should have a unique id'. Job ids are only unique within projects, so the object id is not equal to the job id).

I believe what you want is to do `job.setJobReference(new JobReference().setJobId(...))` instead of `job.setId()`.

Comment: but before it's submitted, I get null from job.getJobReference()

Comment: actually. I try jobRef = new JobReference(), jobRef.setJobId(..), job.setJobReference(jobRef) and then submit that job, and it works.